# Check Google Document text for URL

Tags: google-apps-script, hyperlink, google-docs

We have a Google script that runs as an Add-on and converts basic formatting into basic HTML.

However I can't seem to detect links when they are a full sentence.

Function that should find links ;

```
function processText(item, output) {
var text = item.getText();
var indices = item.getTextAttributeIndices();

Logger.log("processText. "+item+". "+text);

if (indices.length <= 1) {
   var partAtts = item.getAttributes(indices[0]);

// Assuming that a whole para fully italic is a quote
if(item.isBold()) {
  output.push('<b>' + text + '</b>');
}
else if(item.isItalic()) {
  output.push('<blockquote>' + text + '</blockquote>');
}
else if (text.trim().indexOf('http://') > -1) {
  output.push('<a href="' + text + '" rel="nofollow" class="a">' + text + '</a>');
}
else if (text.trim().indexOf('https://') > -1) {
  output.push('<a href="' + text + '" rel="nofollow" class="b">' + text + '</a>');
}
else {
//using this to debug as have no idea how to run from script and use Logger.
  output.push(partAtts[0]+"<<< "+text.trim().indexOf('http://')+ ", "+ text.trim().indexOf('https://')+ " (pt) "+text+". "+indices);
  //output.push(text);
}
} 
else {
...
```

Outputs -

```
<p>A sentence with a <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/oct/19/brexit-talks-uk-must-prepare-to-leave-without-deal-say-former-ministers" class="c">link</a></p>
<p>undefined<<< -1, -1 (pt) A full link sentence. 0</p>
```

This is what the text looks like in the Google Doc.

[image]

Any help appreciated. Really out of my depth here. Even if its just to help me run this from the script editor. ie pick a doc so i can see the log output and increase my trial and error output!

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the logic of your script; it uses the same "text" variable for the URL and link text. Google Documents are not supposed to have bare links like `http://` in the text content; the links are encoded as other text attributes and are accessed with `getLinkUrl`.

Here is my function that goes through all text elements, detects links, and returns HTML format. Note that one text element may contain multiple links. My test case is

> A sentence with a [link](http://example.com) and [another link](https://stackoverflow.com) and more text.
>
> [A full link sentence](http://example.com)

and the output is

```
A sentence with a <a href="http://example.com">link</a> and <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">another link</a> and more text.
<a href="http://example.com">A full link sentence</a>
```

The while-loop goes over text elements; then the for-loop goes over text attribute indices. The `textPart` is the part of text between two indices; the `url` is whatever this part is linked to (possibly `null` if it's not a link). Each part gets pushed to array `output`, with link formatting when applicable. The array is joined and logged.

```
function linkDetection() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var found = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT);
  while (found) {
    var elem = found.getElement();
    var text = elem.getText();
    var output = [];
    var indices = elem.getTextAttributeIndices();
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
      var textPart = (i == indices.length - 1 ? text.slice(indices[i]) : text.slice(indices[i], indices[i+1]));      
      var url = elem.getLinkUrl(indices[i]);
      output.push(url ? '<a href="' + url + '">' + textPart + '</a>' : textPart);
    }
    Logger.log(output.join(''));
    found = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT, found);
  }
}
```